# Is the system of measuring length in the US Turing complete?

Tags: computability, computation-models, turing-completeness

The [author here writes](https://twitter.com/thomasfuchs/status/732751873304858624?refsrc=email&s=11):

> Little known fact, the system of measuring length in the US is Turing complete

[image]

My question is: **Is the system of measuring length in the US Turing complete?**

Comment: I think the author means it as a joke. The measurement system, while certainly intricate and needlessly complex, doesn't look like the right kind of object to be Turing-Complete. It's just a weighted complete graph of conversion factors where the weight on $u\overset{w}{\rightarrow}v$ is the conversion factor from $u$ to $v$. As a stronger argument, this system preserves the parity of the input, in a sense: if $u\overset{a}{\rightarrow}v\overset{b}{\rightarrow}w$ then $u\overset{a\cdot b}{\rightarrow}w$ and $w\overset{\frac{1}{ab}}{\rightarrow}u$. Sorry to disappoint.

Comment: We do not have a senes of humor here.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Perhaps we should have a new tag?

Comment: What would it be, `joke`? In that case I propose we also introduce `kitten-photo`.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Those would be tag synonyms for the real tags `joke-recognition` and `furry-calculus-visualization` respectively. Some more: for programming-related jokes I propose `one-liner`. For compiler fun questions -- `jest-in-time` along with `jit` as a type synonym. For computer architecture topics -- `e-quip-ment`. And, of course, we should get new badges: `Joker`(silver) and `Wildcard`(gold) -- *nix-pun intended. P.S. This question made my day! :) It's a pity it lacks some $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @AndrejBauer If I were to retag questions with [tag:joke], I'm not sure people would feel welcomed.

Comment: What do *you* think? What are the syntax and semantics of a "program" for this model?

Comment: @LieuweVinkhuijzen That's optimistic. They may also be confused about what Turing-completeness means.

Comment: I’m not sure what to make of the fact that the diagram is not commutative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The post you're referring to is a joke: the US (and similar British Imperial) measurement systems are not Turing complete and the claim is an example of [hyperbole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole).

A key feature that's necessary for a system to be Turing complete is that the system must include computations that do not terminate ("infinite loops").  Although it's not clear exactly what computations can be modeled by unit conversions (or what that even means!), any unit conversion within the diagram takes a finite number of steps.

Comment: Wow, it was a real question that got a real answer.